# How do call all data variable array from database ? Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have Column name 'username' in this Column i have data [Brandon01,Cahyono6nz,PutraJatya01] ( Same Column and sameTable )

```
ID      Username
1       Brandon01,Cahyono6nz,PutraJatya01
2       Rumanoin,Nyaman
```

I want show data from that Column
like this

where='ID=01'

```
<td>Brandon01</td>
<td>Cahyono6nz</td>
<td>PutraJatya01</td>
```

Because was i'm using input with function 'Implode' from laravel , i want call that variable from my database with "explode" function , How i can use that ? must i using "for" to call all data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the user's username like this

`$usernames = Model->pluck('Username')->all();`

Where `Model` is the class name of your users table.

After that, you can pass this collection to your view from your controller. And in your controller you can then use as:
`@foreach ($usernames as $username) <td>{{ $username }}</td> @endforeach`

Comment: But my column data using "," / comma , i try like this

`@php
 $name = explode(',',$datasw->username);
                    $username = $name[0];
                    @endphp
                    <td>{{  $username}}</td>`
but i need call all data like
$first_name = $name[1];
$first_name = $name[2];

Comment: What you're trying to say is not clear to me. Explain in a clear way what you want exactly

Comment: I want showing all data from input implode request with explode from table username

condition table like this

`ID      Username`
`1       Brandon01,Cahyono6nz,PutraJatya01`
`2       Rumanoin,Nyaman`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample to loop the usernames in `username` column.

```
// ID      Username
// 1       Brandon01,Cahyono6nz,PutraJatya01
// 2       Rumanoin,Nyaman

// Query
// $data = "select username from `table` where ID = 1;"

// Fetch data
// $data = Contact::where('id',1)->get();

   $data = explode(',','Brandon01,Cahyono6nz,PutraJatya01');
        
   foreach($data as $name) {
      echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
   }
```

But if you want to display all `username` from DB where id in [1,2].

```
$data = Contact::whereIn('id', [1,2])->get()->pluck('username');

foreach($data as $name) {
   echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
   }
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Thanks you but i got problem Trying to get property 'username' of non-object in my blade

 @foreach($siswa as $datasw)
                  <tr>
                  @php
                 ` $name = explode(',',$datasw->username);`
                    @endphp
                    <td>{{$name}}</td>
                  @endforeach

Comment: "non-object" - means that you have no data in your variable. Put if check if you have data only than use explode function

Answer (score -1):

I think after getting the data from the database you should be able to assign it to a variable, explode it and then use foreach

Comment: For this type of vague answers, use comments.